# Why does this Twitter library delay the assignment of its object properties?

Tags: javascript, twitter

[The Twitter widget library](https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) exposes a global variable `twttr`. I'd like to modularize this library on the fly using webpack with exports-loader. The problem is that, while the `twttr` variable is immediately exposed, its properties are still undefined when accessing it synchronously.

```
console.log(twttr.widgets); // undefined 
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(twttr); // now defined
});
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/qisin/1/edit)

So, `var twttr = require('exports?twttr!./path/to/twitter')` will return an object that isn't actually ready to be used.

While the Twitter docs suggest that this is only necessary when loading the library asynchronously, I doubt the widget functions can be used unless wrapped in `twttr.ready`.

At least webpack offers a nicer way of loading the library and accessing `twttr`. I suspect the odd behavior is due to this script coming from a time when module systems were non-existent and SRP was neglected. Nonetheless, I'm quite curious what the developers have done to cause this behavior, and my attempt to read the beautified, minified source code has proven folly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter widget library not only provides API for creating widgets dynamically, but also finds and initializes existing widgets on the page — from the Twitter's [documentation page](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/creating-widgets):

> By default, `widgets-js` will find mark-up in a page and convert basic, functional mark-up into rich interactive widgets.

To do that, it has to scan the DOM and replace matching nodes with `iframe`-s, markup for which are requested from Twitter (which is asynchronous task by its nature).

I suppose, authors decided that initialization of existing widgets may take time and went for doing it completely asynchronously. Now, while library is searching for not yet initialized widgets on the page and updates them, allowing developers to dynamically add new widgets may lead to some concurrency issues. For example it's easy to imagine duplication of requests: library initializer could find a widget added by API and try to initialize it while API has already sent a request to Twitter for `iframe`'s code. The simplest answer to 'How we prevent that?' would be to hide API from the client while library works on existing widgets.

Comment: I could see that. That lines up with my suspicion that this was caused by neglecting SRP.